# How to manage object lifetime when working with COM interop?

Tags: com, com-interop

I have a managed COM object written in C# and a native COM client and sink written in C++ (MFC and ATL).  The client creates the object and advises to its event interface at startup, and unadvises from its event interface and releases the object at shutdown.  The problem is that the COM object has a reference to the sink which is not released until garbage collection runs, at which point the client is already torn down and thus usually results in an access violation.  It's probably not that big of a deal since the client is shutting down anyway, but I would like to resolve this gracefully if possible.  I need my COM object to release my sink object in a more timely manner, and I don't really know where to start since my COM object doesn't work with the sink object explicitly.

My COM object:

```
public delegate void TestEventDelegate(int i);

[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface ITestObject
{
    int TestMethod();
    void InvokeTestEvent();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface ITestObjectEvents
{
    void TestEvent(int i);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ITestObjectEvents))]
public class TestObject : ITestObject
{
    public event TestEventDelegate TestEvent;
    public TestObject() { }
    public int TestMethod()
    {
        return 42;
    }
    public void InvokeTestEvent()
    {
        if (TestEvent != null)
        {
            TestEvent(42);
        }
    }
}
```

The client is a standard MFC dialog-based program, with added support for ATL.  My sink class:

```
class CTestObjectEventsSink : public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>, public ITestObjectEvents
{
public:
    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CTestObjectEventsSink)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_IID(__uuidof(ITestObjectEvents), ITestObjectEvents)
    END_COM_MAP()
    HRESULT __stdcall raw_TestEvent(long i)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }
};
```

I have the following members in my dialog class:

```
ITestObjectPtr m_TestObject;
CComObject<CTestObjectEventsSink>* m_TestObjectEventsSink;
DWORD m_Cookie;
```

In OnInitDialog():

```
HRESULT hr = m_TestObject.CreateInstance(__uuidof(TestObject));
if(m_TestObject)
{
    hr = CComObject<CTestObjectEventsSink>::CreateInstance(&m_TestObjectEventsSink);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        m_TestObjectEventsSink->AddRef(); // CComObject::CreateInstace() gives an object with a ref count of 0
        hr = AtlAdvise(m_TestObject, m_TestObjectEventsSink, __uuidof(ITestObjectEvents), &m_Cookie);
    }
}
```

In OnDestroy():

```
if(m_TestObject)
{
    HRESULT hr = AtlUnadvise(m_TestObject, __uuidof(ITestObjectEvents), m_Cookie);
    m_Cookie = 0;
    m_TestObjectEventsSink->Release();
    m_TestObjectEventsSink = NULL;
    m_TestObject.Release();
}
```

Comment: Looks to me you are forgetting m_TestObjectEventsSink->Release().  It is not automatic since you store a pointer to CComObject<>, you are probably just leaking it.  Not sure why that would be necessary.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Forgot about those, but the effect is the same as CComObject::CreateInstance() gives you an object with a ref count of 0.  I'll update the question regardless.

Comment: CComObject::CreateInstance() gives you an object with a ref count of 0; it is your responsibility to AddRef() it.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I'll just say that I've used your example code to implement a copy of what you have described, but I don't see any access violations when testing either Debug or Release builds.

So it is possible that there is some alternative explanation to what you're seeing (e.g. you may need to call `Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject` if you hold other interfaces to the native client).

There is a comprehensive description of when/when not to call `ReleaseCOMObject` on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647812.aspx#scalenetchapt07%20_topic9).

Having said that, you're right that your C# COM object doesn't work with the COM client's sink object *directly*, but it *does* communicate with it through the C# event object. This allows you to implement a customised event object so you can trap the effect of the client's calls to `AtlAdvise` and `AtlUnadvise`.

For example, you can reimplement your event as follows (with some debugging output added):

```cs
private event TestEventDelegate _TestEvent;
public event TestEventDelegate TestEvent
{
    add
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TRACE : TestObject.TestEventDelegate.add() called");
        _TestEvent += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TRACE : TestObject.TestEventDelegate.remove() called");
        _TestEvent -= value;
    }
}

public void InvokeTestEvent()
{
    if (_TestEvent != null)
    {
        _TestEvent(42);
    }
}
```

To continue with the debugging output, you can add similar diagnostics to the MFC/ATL application and see exactly when the reference count is updated on the sink interface (note that this assumes Debug builds of *both* projects). So, for example, I added a `Dump` method to the sink implementation:

```cpp
class CTestObjectEventsSink : public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>, public ITestObjectEvents
{
public:
    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CTestObjectEventsSink)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_IID(__uuidof(ITestObjectEvents), ITestObjectEvents)
    END_COM_MAP()
    HRESULT __stdcall raw_TestEvent(long i)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }
    void Dump(LPCTSTR szMsg)
    {
        TRACE("TRACE : CTestObjectEventsSink::Dump() - m_dwRef = %u (%S)\n", m_dwRef, szMsg);
    }
};
```

Then, running the Debug client application through the IDE, you can see what's happening. First, during creation of the COM object:

```cpp
HRESULT hr = m_TestObject.CreateInstance(__uuidof(TestObject));
if(m_TestObject)
{
    hr = CComObject<CTestObjectEventsSink>::CreateInstance(&m_TestObjectEventsSink);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        m_TestObjectEventsSink->Dump(_T("after CreateInstance"));
        m_TestObjectEventsSink->AddRef(); // CComObject::CreateInstace() gives an object with a ref count of 0
        m_TestObjectEventsSink->Dump(_T("after AddRef"));
        hr = AtlAdvise(m_TestObject, m_TestObjectEventsSink, __uuidof(ITestObjectEvents), &m_Cookie);
        m_TestObjectEventsSink->Dump(_T("after AtlAdvise"));
    }
}
```

This gives the following debug output (you can see the C# trace from the `AtlAdvise` call in there)

`TRACE : CTestObjectEventsSink::Dump() - m_dwRef = 0 (after CreateInstance)`
`TRACE : CTestObjectEventsSink::Dump() - m_dwRef = 1 (after AddRef)`
`TRACE : TestObject.TestEventDelegate.add() called`
`TRACE : CTestObjectEventsSink::Dump() - m_dwRef = 2 (after AtlAdvise)`

This looks as expected, we have a reference count of 2 - one from the native code `AddRef` and another (presumably) from `AtlAdvise`.

Now, you can check what happens if the `InvokeTestEvent()` method is called - here I do it twice:

```cpp
m_TestObject->InvokeTestEvent();
m_TestObjectEventsSink->Dump(_T("after m_TestObject->InvokeTestEvent() first call"));
m_TestObject->InvokeTestEvent();
m_TestObjectEventsSink->Dump(_T("after m_TestObject->InvokeTestEvent() second call"));
```

This is the corresponding trace

```
TRACE : CTestObjectEventsSink::Dump() - m_dwRef = 3 (after m_TestObject->InvokeTestEvent() first call)   
TRACE : CTestObjectEventsSink::Dump() - m_dwRef = 3 (after m_TestObject->InvokeTestEvent() second call)
```

You can see that an additional `AddRef` has happened, the first time the event is fired. I'm guessing that this is the reference that doesn't get released until garbage collection.

Finally, in `OnDestroy`, we can see the reference count going down again. The code is

```cpp
if(m_TestObject)
{
    m_TestObjectEventsSink->Dump(_T("before AtlUnadvise"));
    HRESULT hr = AtlUnadvise(m_TestObject, __uuidof(ITestObjectEvents), m_Cookie);
    m_TestObjectEventsSink->Dump(_T("after AtlUnadvise"));
    m_Cookie = 0;
    m_TestObjectEventsSink->Release();
    m_TestObjectEventsSink->Dump(_T("after Release"));
    m_TestObjectEventsSink = NULL;
    m_TestObject.Release();
}
```

and the trace output is

`TRACE : CTestObjectEventsSink::Dump() - m_dwRef = 3 (before AtlUnadvise)`
`TRACE : TestObject.TestEventDelegate.remove() called`
`TRACE : CTestObjectEventsSink::Dump() - m_dwRef = 3 (after AtlUnadvise)`
`TRACE : CTestObjectEventsSink::Dump() - m_dwRef = 2 (after Release)`

So you can see that `AtlUnadvise` doesn't affect the reference count ([also noted by other people](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ccffe5c-3cd3-4ef2-bcb6-01056766fa1d/refcount-remains-unchanged-after-atlunadvise-call)) but also note that we got a trace from the `remove` accessor of the C# COM object event, which is a possible location for forcing some garbage collection or other tear-down tasks.

To summarise:

1. You reported access violations with the code you posted but I could not reproduce that error, so it is possible that the error you see is unrelated to the problem you described.
2. You asked how you could interact with the COM client sink, and I have shown one potential way using a customised event implementation. This is supported with debug output showing how the two COM components interact.

I really hope this is helpful. There are some alternative COM handling tips and more explanations in [this old but otherwise excellent blog post](http://radio-weblogs.com/0111019/stories/2002/08/05/connectionPointBasedEventHandlingBetweenComAndnet.html).

Comment: I'm not sure that blog post is relevant.  It is consuming a COM object in managed code, and customizing it to be released deterministically.  In my case the COM object itself is managed and being consumed in native code.  In the managed code I never have a reference to the event sink so I can't call ReleaseComObject() on it.  I will look at forcing GC during event.remove() and see if that does anything.

Comment: Forcing GC during event.remove() does not appear to decrement the ref count.

Comment: @Luke yes, sorry, the blog post is there because I'd found it useful in the past but you're right it's for the opposite case to yours. Also, I tried GC.Collect too but I think the COM wrapper is still being held open until the object itself is gone. My main concern was the lack of an access violation though so I couldn't proceed to try to debug why. I thought that by being able to trap AtlUnadvise you may be able to apply clear-up for that problem there.

Comment: The access violation does not occur in the sample program because it is a minimal reproduction of the underlying behavior (sink not being released until process exit).  In the real code the sink destructor accesses a global object which has already been destroyed.  Unfortunately it is not feasible to change this since it is a generic mechanism used for all our event sinks (of which there are many).

Comment: @Luke I see - is it feasible to move the sink dtor code to the same place as the AtlUnadvise?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question but we recently came across this problem as well, and the solution we found was to add a call to `CoEEShutDownCOM()` as part of our shutdown process.

Calling that seems to force the CLR to release any references it has to our (unmanaged) COM objects. Note that the docs say it is deprecated in .Net 4 (and they suggest an alternative method which we haven't tried).